# Como acessar atributo herdado em uma entidade com uma query no Spring Data

Tags: java, herança, spring-data

Galera, tenho a entidade Cliente que extende Pessoa:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "cliente")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="id_pessoa")
@Document(indexName="cliente")
public class Cliente extends Pessoa implements Serializable {
```

Pessoa tem o atributo:

```
@Column(name = "nm_pessoa")
private String nome;
```

No meu repositório tenho:

```
public interface ClienteRepository extends JpaRepository<Cliente,Long> {

//Esse metodo funciona
Page<Cliente> findById(Long id, Pageable pageable);

/*Esse método não retorna nada já que no banco de dados
  os dados estão na outra tabela: pessoa
*/
@Query("SELECT c FROM Cliente c where c.nome like :nome%") //missing order by clause    
Page<Cliente> findByNomeStartingWithOrderByNomeAsc(@Param("nome") String nome, Pageable pageable);
```

Como eu posso fazer essa consulta, pegando o nome que está em outra tabela fisicamente no banco de dados, sendo que está na entidade Cliente através de herança.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Galera descobri o problema, a questão é que na minha entidade Pessoa o atributo está mapeado como nome_pessoa mas na entidade está como nome.

Depois dos testes funcionou, o SpringData consegue acessar atributos herdados de outras classes e com nomes diferentes no banco de dados em relação a entidade em sí.

Comment: Marca a pergunta como resolvida.